# Self union MultiPolygon layer using GeoPandas

Tags: polygon, geopandas, overlapping-features, polygon-creation, union

I need to perform a union operation inside a single layer. In QGIS there is an option not to select the second layer, but I can't figure out how to do it in GeoPandas?

Example:

[image]

Plots are red, zones are green.

From this photo, I should get the following result:

[image]

In Qgis, when merging, the sections are separated in the case of using a single layer. When using two, not all sections are highlighted

Comment: Red polygon is one layer, green polygons are another layer. These are polygons, not multipolygons. No, I need to do exactly the merge operation, inside one layer, and I need to do it between two, as geopandas suggests.

Comment: You talk about both merge and union which are not the same. Do you want exactly what you get in QGIS when using Union and only using your zone layer as input layer, and no Overlay layer?

Comment: This is a reservation. I mean only union.  Yes I want to get the same result in geopandas as when using the union operation in QGIS without using overlay

Comment: What was the problem with the output of the self-union answer?

Comment: Not all intersection objects are separated from each other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a list of dataframes where each dataframe is one row of your original df. Then union all of them using [reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
import geopandas as gpd
from functools import reduce

zone = gpd.read_file(r"/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/zones.geojson")
plot = gpd.read_file(r"/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/plot.geojson")

plot_clip = gpd.overlay(plot, zone, how="intersection") #Clip the plots with the zone df

plot_clip["ID"] = range(0, plot_clip.shape[0]) #Create a unique ID column
plot_clip = plot_clip[["ID","geometry"]] #Drop all columns but ID and geometry

#Create one frame for each ID/row and store in frames list
frames = []
for ID, frame in plot_clip.groupby("ID"):
    frames.append(frame[["geometry"]])

#Union all data frames: df1 & df2 = output1, output1 & df3 = output2, output2 & df4 = output3 and so on...:
union = reduce(lambda frame1, frame2: gpd.overlay(frame1, frame2, how="union"), frames)
union.to_file(r"/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/plot_UNION.geojson")
```

[image]